# mongodb aggregate $redact to filter array elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In mongodb 3.4.5 think below simple collection `ooo`:

```
{ "id" : 1, "to" : [ { "id" : 2 }, { "id" : 4, "valid" : true } ] }
```

Want to `$redact` `to` if `valid` **not** true:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
         "if": { "$ne": [ "$valid", true] },
         "then": "$$KEEP",
         "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}])
```

Result:

```
{ "id" : 1, "to" : [ { "id" : 2 } ] }
```

But when changed condition to if `valid` **is** true:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
         "if": { "$eq": [ "$valid", true] },
         "then": "$$KEEP",
         "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}])
```

The result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The `$redact` walks the whole documents from top level then downwards, the `"$valid": true` part cannot pass on top level (top level have no `valid` field), then the `$$ROOT` be `$$PRUNE`d, and nothing returned.

The solution (skip this and see below updated):

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
         "if": { $or: ["$to", {"$eq": [ "$valid", true]}] },
         "then": "$$KEEP",
         "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}])
```

**UPDATE**:

based on @neil's comment, I corrected the answer:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
         "if": { $or: ["$to", {"$eq": [ "$valid", true]}] },
         "then": "$$DESCEND",
         "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}])
```

And the expected result shown:

```
{ "id" : 1, "to" : [ { "id" : 4, "valid" : true } ] }
```

That is the `{ "id" : 2 }` be pruned.

Comment: Umm. No it does not. The **only** time it "walks though" is when you explicitly use `$$DESCEND`, which you have not. So all conditions are evaluated at the "top level" **only**. Seems you misread the documentation. [Might need to read it again](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend)