# mongodb $or syntax in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb I found a strange behavior of `$or`, think below collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "to" : [ { "_id" : 2 }, { "_id" : 4, "valid" : true } ] }
```

When aggregate with `$match`:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{$match:{ $or: ['$to', '$valid'] }}])
```

Will throw error with `aggregate failed`: (sure, I know how to fix it...)

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue"
```

But If the `$or` used in a `$cond` statement:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
        "if": { $or: ["$to", "$valid"] },
        "then": "$$DESCEND",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
}}])
```

The result will shown and no error thrown, see [mongodb aggregate $redact to filter array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710800/mongodb-aggregate-redact-to-filter-array-elements)

The question is what's going on with the `$or` syntax? why the same condition not work in `$match` but **did work** in `$cond`?

Also I'm looked up the docs:

**$cond**

> If the  evaluates to true, then $cond evaluates and returns the value of the  expression. Otherwise, $cond evaluates and returns the value of the  expression.
>
> The arguments can be any valid expression. For more information on expressions, see Expressions.

**$or**

> Evaluates one or more expressions and returns true if any of the expressions are true. Otherwise, $or returns false.
>
> For more information on expressions, see Expressions.

PS: I'm using mongodb 3.4.5 but not tested on other version.

I don't have a clue...

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer of @Neil, I'm also tried the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) usage with `$or`:

1.

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$project": {
  result:{
    "$filter": {
        "input": "$to",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": {$or: ["$$el.valid"]}
    }
  }
}}])
```

2.

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$project": {
  result:{
    "$filter": {
        "input": "$to",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": {$or: "$$el.valid"}
    }
  }
}}])
```

3.

```
db.ooo.aggregate([{ "$project": {
  result:{
    "$filter": {
        "input": "$to",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": "$$el.valid"
    }
  }
}}])
```

All the above 3 `$filter`, the syntax are ok, the result is shown and no error thrown.

Seems `$or` will work with field names directly only in `$cond` or `cond`?

Or this is a hacking usage of `$or`?

Comment: Dude. [Read the comment on your last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710800/mongodb-aggregate-redact-to-filter-array-elements). You are doing it wrong, and therefore the self answer is invalid. What are  you trying to do here? Select the documents where `"valid"` boolean exists in the array and is `true`? Or "filter" the items from the array keeping only wher the `"valid"` field is `true`?

Comment: @NeilLunn The latter, "filter" the items from the array keeping only where the "valid" field is true. I'm updated the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710800/mongodb-aggregate-redact-to-filter-array-elements/44710801#44710801)

Comment: Use the oddly named [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) then. Or are you using a MongoDB version like 2.x where that operator is not present?

Comment: Keeping silent isn't helping you. Read the response in the answer, since I see what you are trying to do but I explain why it cannot work with `$redact` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline stage is the is the wrong thing for this type of operation. Instead use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) which actually "filters" things from arrays:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "to": {
       "$filter": {
         "input": "$to",
         "as": "t",
         "cond": { "$ifNull": [ "$$t.valid", false ] }
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

Produces:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594c5b0a212a102096cebf7e"),
        "id" : 1,
        "to" : [
                {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "valid" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

The problem with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) in this case is the only way you can actually "redact" from an array is by using `$$DESCEND` on the `false` condition. This is recursive and evaluates the expression from the top level of the document downwards. At whatever level where the condition is not met, [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) will discard it. No `"valid"`field in the "top-level" means it would discard the whole document, unless we gave an alternate condition.

Since not all array elements have the `"valid"` field in "addition" to the top level of the document, we cannot even "hack it" to pretend something is there.

For example you appear to be trying to do this:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$or": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$$ROOT.to", false ] },
          "$valid"
       ]
      },
      "then": "$$DESCEND",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

But when you look carefully, that kind of comparison will essentially "always" evaluate to `true`, no matter how hard you tried to hack a condition.

You could do:

```
db.ooo.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$or": [
          { "$ifNull": [ "$to", false ] },
          "$valid"
       ]
      },
      "then": "$$DESCEND",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Which does correctly remove the element from the array:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594c5b0a212a102096cebf7e"),
        "id" : 1,
        "to" : [
                {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "valid" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

But it is overkill and adds unnecessary overhead to logic processing when the simple [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) will do in this case. You should only need this form when there are actually "nested" arrays that need to be recursively processed, and all conditions can actually be met at all levels.

The lesson here is to use the correct operators for their designed purpose.

Comment: I'm really learned from this post with the different of [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), my understand now: the `$filter` will target within a specific level of document, and `$redact` will walk through all the level from top, to every children. So for efficiency and reducing error ( cough the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710800/mongodb-aggregate-redact-to-filter-array-elements) cough ), choose `$filter` first with array in fixed level.

Comment: @NeiLunn I'm thinking of accept your answer, but the question is about the "$or syntax in aggregation pipeline", your answer is useful but not about the question?

Comment: @JamesYang Dude. I'm showing you the correct thing to do as well as **also** showing the corrected syntax for `$or` if you actually read all of it. Read it. Because it does not seem like you are.